# How can I get list of few top android market apps through code

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play

I am wondering how can I get list of top android apps package names from market through java code?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the market does not have an API you can call to get this stuff.  It is closed source and Google wants people in the market to see this data.

You could try page scraping but I am sure that is against some ToS somewhere, and will break very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Actually take a look at the `URL` of the applications in Android Market : `https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds&feature=top-free`  - the package name of the application is the `package name=com.rovio.angrybirds` or `https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftBPHM.ML&feature=top-paid` - `package name=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftBPHM.ML` That should be the answer if I understand your question correct.

Comment: Actually i want to download few top apps at once through code. Can we do that? If yes then shed a light on this, how?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to download top apps via your android application?